# Plotly graph is collapsed in Jupyter Lab unless I specify the height

Tags: plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-python

When I try to plot a Plotly graph, the height is set to near 0 or something, because the graph renders collapsed. What I'm seeing:

[image: Collapsed Graph]

However, if I manually set the graph's height, it renders correctly. How can I get the graphs to render correctly without manually setting the height?

Code for repro collapsed graph:

```py
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "jupyterlab"
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")
fig.show()
```

Now make the graph show:

```py
fig.layout.height = 500
fig.show()
```

I'm running this with the following setup:

- Docker Ubuntu 22.04
- plotly==5.14.1
- jupyterlab==4.0.0
- ipywidgets==8.0.3

Comment: This looks like a bug in JupyterLab 4.0. Could you go to `Settings` → `Settings Editor` → `Notebook` → `Windowing Mode` → switch to `none` → save and reload → report back if the issue persists?

Comment: @krassowski - thanks for your response. I tried that but the issue still persists

Comment: There seems to be a pull request for this one here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/pull/4217

Comment: Honestly, the `fig.layout.height = 500` was already a solution for me XD

Comment: Hey guys, I had this same problem in jupyter notebook 7

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to add `autosize = False` to the template layout. Henceforth, you should no longer need to explicitly define `fig.layout.height`.

In the example below I have added it to the `plotly` template:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates['plotly'].layout['autosize'] = False # <---This did the trick.

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")
fig.show()
```

You can also add it to all the templates in the following manner:

```
for key in pio.templates.keys():
    pio.templates[key].layout['autosize'] = False
```

---

Package versions:

- plotly==5.15.0
- jupyterlab==4.0.5
- ipywidgets==8.0.6