# Jupyter notebook cell with result too small

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I had a Jupyter notebook for plotting some data with plotly. Last time I commited it, worked OK, but now the cell where plots are shown is extremly small, I can't see anything

[image]

I think Jupyter got updated in between and that broke it.

For reproduction, this is the notebook https://github.com/miguel9554/tesis-redaccion/blob/master/plots/pulse_comparison.ipynb

Comment: This has also been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325663/plotly-graph-is-collapsed-in-jupyter-lab-unless-i-specify-the-height, I solved it with the fig.height = 500 stuff